# boto3 Client Error: Server Side Encryption with Customer provided key is incompatible with the encryption method specified

Tags: python, django, encryption, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using boto3 with my django application to upload some files to S3. But I receive the following error when I try to specify the client side encryption algorithm and and keys using [boto3's Object's API](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object).

> An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutObject
>   operation: Server Side Encryption with Customer provided key is
>   incompatible with the encryption method specified.

Here is my code for specifying Encryption algorithm and keys.

```
    import boto3
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    key = s3.Object(bucket_name, key_name)
    file_obj.seek(0)
    kwargs = {
        'ServerSideEncryption': 'AES256',
        'SSECustomerAlgorithm': 'AES256',
        'SSECustomerKey': settings.AWS_ENCRYPTION_KEY,
    }

    key.put(**kwargs)
    key.put(Body=file_obj)
    key.Acl().put(ACL='public-read')
```

And here is how I generate the encryption key in settings.py

```
# settings.py
password = '32characterslongpassphraseneeded'.encode('utf-8')
AWS_ENCRYPTION_KEY = base64.b64encode(password)
```

## Update

I'm using python3.

Comment: I give up. It seems all working samples are in java/nodejs. Other sample in the net seems not working. I think you should open an issues in boto3 github  https://github.com/boto/boto3    There is possible unknown bug in the botocore.

Comment: I did open up and issue to thats asks for a working example one day ago. Still no response from the contributors. https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/684

Comment: @mootmoot finally got the response from the contributors. A working example is there now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After posting an issue on boto3 library I finally got a working example. Here is how it should be done.

```
import boto3
import os

BUCKET = 'YOUR-BUCKET'
KEY = os.urandom(32)
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
print("Put object...")
s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET,
              Key='path_of_object_in_bucket', Body=b'foobar',
              SSECustomerKey=KEY,
              SSECustomerAlgorithm='AES256')
print("Done")
# Make sure to save the KEY!

# Getting the object:
print("Getting object...")
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET,
                         Key='path_of_object_in_bucket',
                         SSECustomerKey=KEY,
                         SSECustomerAlgorithm='AES256')
print("Done, response body:")
print(response['Body'].read())
```

Comment: This is 32 bytes raw binary, definitely NOT base64-encoded key as stated in AWS documentation. Though require of base64-encoded is not mentioned in boto3 documentation.